# Chef Template - Timestamping

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

While implementing a templated config file using chef 11.x I'd like to insert the current date/time into the file whenever it is updated.

For example:

```
# Created By : core::time-settings
# On         : <%= Time.now %>
```

Obviously this evaluates on each recipe run and constantly updates the target file even when the other attributes are OK - which is not desired.

Therefore is anyone aware of a solution?  I'm not aware of any built-in logic within Chef to achieve this and I don't know of a built-in chef variable that I could evaluate within a ruby block that would only be true if the other attributes are out of compliance (as that would provide a potential workaround).

I know that I could run an execute type operation which only gets run after the template resource has been fired, and it expands a variable in the file to achieve this, but I don't like the concept or idea of doing that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I agree with [Tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai) that what you expect is not what Chef is made for.

What I want to add (because some time ago I searched pretty long for that) is how to include the current time stamp in a file, once it was modified through Chef (somehow you have to circumvent that it always updates the time stamp).

The result can be found [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-pdns/blob/7aff686016e77a4130e8892c9a4639b07ec91afa/providers/zone.rb#L36-L67), simplified, untested version:

```rb
  time =  Time.new.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

  template "/tmp/example.txt" do
    source    "/tmp/example.txt.erb" # the source is not in a cookbook, but on the disk of the node!
    local     true
    variables(
      :time => time
    )
    action :nothing
  end

  template "/tmp/example.txt.erb" do
    variables(
      variable1 => "test"
     )
    notifies :create, resources(:template => "/tmp/example.txt"), :immediately
  end
```

Everytime, when the content of `/tmp/example.txt.erb` changes, it triggers `/tmp/example.txt` to be written - taking `/tmp/example.txt.erb` as template from the local disk instead of from the cookbook (because `local true`) and replacing the `time` variable with the current time.

So the only variable that has to be replaced when writing `/tmp/example.txt` is the time, thus the `example.txt.erb` template looks like this:

```
# my template
time: <%%= @time %>
other stuff here.. <%= @variable1 %>
```

Comment: Nice one (even if I still don't see a use case), maybe worth noting the `<%%= ` is to have a `<%= ` in the renderer local template source which will be replaced by the second template call.

Comment: Thanks for that note! The actual use case was linked in the answer: For [PowerDNS](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-pdns/blob/7aff686016e77a4130e8892c9a4639b07ec91afa/providers/zone.rb#L36-L67) I render a zone file from a template. Such a DNS zone needs a serial, usually derived from the current time. But I want to update the serial only, when a change of the template (new host, change in IP etc) occurred.

Comment: Indeed, this is a clear use case :) You're welcome for the note.

Comment: Haha @StephenKing, exactly the reason I was looking for a way to do this (except I'm creating a custom cookbook for bind) :D

Answer (score 1):

That's the way chef works, it makes a diff between rendered template and actual file, as the timestamp is not the same it replace it.

Your alternate solution won't work either for the same reason, a placeholder will be different than the datetime of the replacements.

The best you can do is write a file aside named 'myfile-last-update' for exemple with a text inside describing the last update of it.

But last question: Why would you want to have the time inside the file as it's already present in the file attribute (`ls -l` should give you this information) ?

Comment: The attributes of the file are not necessarily when chef last edited it - outside forces could have edited and/or touched the file in the interim, so having a timestamp in the file would provide some information to anyone who reads the file.

Comment: If an outside force touch the file, chef will rewrite it... and the outside force won't always update the timestamp at top of the file, so I don't get what it can gives you at all...

Comment: That assumes that chef will be run on a regular basis which may not be the case in some environments - therefore the delta between chef runs may be significant.  I know that this is far from ideal but this in combination with historical layout of certain files is the reason I was looking to implement something along these lines.

Comment: Chef will output a diff when it overwrites the file (and it backups it in /var/chef/backups with a timestamp). A timestamp inside the file tis not reliable in any way, it's a lure thinking it will gives anything trustable. Anyway, chef templates are not designed this way, so probably not the tool for what you try to achieve if you really wish the time in the file.